# multiple conflicting regex replacements on string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, source-maps

I am in the middle of making a simple pattern matcher using regex, which can take my regex patterns, and produce a new string in the format I desire. What seemed like a simple program at first became very complex when i noticed that I had adjacent regex patterns that conflicted with eachother, and could no longer perform the operation correctly, because the newly formed string contained characters that would conflict with something I had just replace... (i know its probably a little confusing, so i'll provide an example).

```
var str = "I am the greatest";
var r1 = /(am)/g;
var r2 = /(i)/ig;
var newstr = str.replace(r1,"<i>$1</i>").replace(r2,"<h1>$1</h2>");
console.log(newstr);
    //returns "<h1>I</h2> <<h1>i</h2>>am</<h1>i</h2>> the greatest"
```

I know that this is a naive example, however, it illustrates my point perfectly. What I would like to happen is for the second (and all proceeding) replacements to perform it's match on the original string, but do its replacement on the mutated string so that the `newstr` var in the above example would read `"<h1>I</h2> <i>am</i> the greatest"`. I've thought of using sourcemaps, to reference a map of the regexs and perform a custom replace function which references the map to perform the replacement at the correct location.... but i cant seem to get a grasp on sourcemaps enough to implement this.... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is there any limit for str? for example not using # or _?

Comment: In this particular case you can just using regexp in another order so later regexp wouldn't include patterns that mach replacements of earlier.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov str would be in the form standard english sentences. thus, it wouldnt have special characters like `~` , `#`, `_` or backticks. and very rarely would have triangle brackets (although, i can think of a few case instances where it could).

Comment: @stribizhev my first attempt at this, i tried pre-sorting my patterns, so that the affects of a previous pattern did not conflict with the current. However, as i continued to add more patterns, things just got too complex to keep track of. As for your 2nd question, there would not be any tags or weird characters that would not be standard in an English sentence before the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could come up with a sequence of characters that you'll expect to never find in the string, use that sequence to temporarily wrap the results of all your `replace`ments, then strip that sequence after all `replace`ments are finished.

Example, choosing the sequence to be `#{...}`, you'd prepend that to all your regex patterns.  Something like:

```
var seq = /#\{(.*?)\}/g; // our sequence -- #{...}

// Prepend (#\{(.*?)\})| to the given regex
var newExpression = function(regex) {
    var splitRegex = regex.toString().split('/'),
        flags = splitRegex.pop();
    splitRegex.shift(); // get rid of the first blank entry from the opening '/' in the regex
    return new RegExp('(' + seq.toString().slice(1, -2) + ')|' + splitRegex.join('/'), flags);
};

var r1 = newExpression(/(am)/g); // returns /(#\{(.*?)\})|(am)/g
var r2 = newExpression(/(i)/ig); // returns /(#\{(.*?)\})|(i)/ig
```

would do it, if you don't want to manually add `(#\{.*?\})|` to the beginning of all your patterns.  We do this so that we can recognize this sequence in subsequent passes and not touch it.

Next, make sure to stick `#{` on the beginning of all matches and `}` on the end;

```
str.replace(r1, '#{<i>$1</i>}')...
```

would accomplish that.  Unfortunately, this isn't quite intelligent enough for us--we need to leave items that match our sequence (`#{...}`) alone; in other words, replace them with themselves.  Here's a function that'll do that for us nicely:

```
var replaceFunc = function(match) {
    return match.match(seq)
        ? match
        : '#{<' + this.tag + '>' + match + '</' + this.tag + '>}';
};
```

Then use it like:

```
var newStr = str.replace(r1, replaceFunc.bind({tag: 'i'}))
    .replace(r2, replaceFunc.bind({tag: 'h1'}))
    .replace(seq, '$1'); // strip the sequence, leaving the desired string
```

Of course, I understand that you won't necessarily be using HTML tags in your actual implementation, and this sequence might not be sufficient.  But you should now be able to easily modify `seq`, `replaceFunc`, and/or the objects to which you bind `replaceFunc` to suit your needs.

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ohz09a56/).  Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks. I will try an implementation of this and get back to you. It seems to show the most promise.

Answer (score 0):

As I saw in ur first replacement you replace am to *am*, so in the second you replace all i, it means that you replace not only "I" and <"i">,  too, so you get the result you've written.
Here is the regexp, that couldn't replace tag "i":

```
r2 = /(i)[^>]/ig
```

Comment: And in replacement string you should add space after </h2> tag

Comment: Although, i can see that your solution is correct for the example I've given, the reason i framed my question the way I have is because, not all replacements will be in the form of a tag. The solution I'm looking for would be a general purpose solution which takes into account the fact that a replacement could include characters which are valid in a subsequent match. (hope that makes sense)